# How does phpmyadmin finds and calls the web browser

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to know this because I want that localhost or phpmyadmin will not be accessible on the web browser(portable or installed). Is there any setting in phpmyadmin which identifies where the web browser is? Would the trick of uninstalling the web browser set as default browser for viewing localhost work? I just want it to be inaccessible when users left click on wamp and select phpmyadmin or localhost.

Comment: Why would users have the option to left click on *your* wamp server and select either *phpmyadmin* or *localhost*? I am confused to that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstalling a browser will not make a website go away.
2. Just because you're using a web browser to view `localhost`, it doesn't mean that site is being viewed or is accessible via the Internet.
3. You can block external access to your WAMP machine via the Apache settings, or your home router settings. In general though, you'd have to actually *enable* it in the first place.

I don't mean to sound rude, but it sounds as though you have some serious misconceptions about how the Internet works. It might be worth doing some research on that.

Comment: No, the webpage is not on the internet. And I'm just a beginner. What I want is to make the shortcut in wampserver useless. Because the default thing that happens when you click on phpmyadmin is that a web browser will open. All I want to do is that a web browser will not open if you click on phpmyadmin or localhost.